# Chrome load tab without selecting it

Tags: google-chrome

The question is opposite to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/811965/how-to-make-chrome-not-load-tabs-until-they-are-selected) one.

Say I open link in a new tab. Currently it is opened, but not loaded. It starts loading only when I select it. I want so that I open a lot of links on a page and those tabs start loading without need to be selected.

Furthermore, there is another problem. When I open link, select that tab, tab is loaded. Then I go to another tab, do something there and return to the first tab. So this tab starts to reload again.

How to fix this?

My version of Chrome is - 48.0.2564.116. It starts to happen recently.

Comment: I am not certainly sure but are you using a small laptop like atom or celeron, or netbook etc? I believe this is because of this is how chrome keeps it's performance by avoiding to using too much system resources.

Comment: @siniradam I added new answer. No, I do use a desktop with intel core i3. But now my computer does not work as fast as it did when I bought it.

Comment: yes I found same answer aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is https://superuser.com/questions/1048029/disable-auto-refresh-tabs-in-chrome-desktop#answer-1049471. Shorter, the flag `#automatic-tab-discarding` needs to be disabled on `chrome://flags`.

Comment: This answer prevents the reload of a tab, the second problem from your original question. I am experiencing (and being annoyed by) your first mentioned problem: "Chrome load tab without selecting it". Did you find any solution to this @FreeLightman

Answer (score 0):

If you are using (in settings) "continue where you left off" then switch to "Open specific page or set of pages" try it there, then switch back

Comment: How that can help me? I tell about real - time using a browser.

Comment: I mentioned that because after updating to version 48.0.2564.116 I suffered the same issue but after switching the tabs that were being opened on start-up it stopped not loading them until clicked. Sorry if it was not helpful